# Identifying users who are sharing

Tags: macos, terminal, file-sharing, restart

When I select Restart from the Apple menu and get the alert "There is a user sharing this computer...", I would like to know which user (e.g. their IP address or some other identification) is sharing.  Is there a (Terminal) command to discover the addresses of sharing users?  (I'm not suspecting unauthorised users, rather I am trying to identify the source of a problem).

Comment: what kind of sharing do you have activated in your sys pref sharing.

Comment: there are 2 kind of sharing. The Internet/Network and the no Internet/Network = Users of the computer.

Comment: Network sharing.

Answer (score 1):

For network sharing you could do following in Terminal.

Assuming you have the file sharing enabled.

Applications using a file reference to your computer can mount a remote disk automatically, as long as the computer is on the network. A command like

```
netstat -na | grep 548
```

will list what machine and user is connected by AFP.

If you simply type `netstat` it will list all active connection.